# How to get the exact parameter in a store procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to records from my Sales table with two parameters based on the month. Instead of the getting the exact months chosen, it fires me all the records. How can I go about it?

When I include the column Monat in a WHERE Clause, then I get an empty results

My sp:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[spMonthInfo]
(   
@Periode1 NVARCHAR (255),
@Periode2 NVARCHAR (255) 
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Dynamictbl nvarchar(MAX) =
N'SELECT
[t].[Monat], [t].[Project],[t].[Description],
[t].[Finance], --[t].[Project] AS [Entrance],

SUM(CASE WHEN [t].Monat = ' + @Periode1 + ' THEN [t].[Amount1] END) AS [Amount1Feb],
SUM(CASE WHEN [t].Monat = ' + @Periode2 + ' THEN [t].[Amount1] END) AS [Amount1March],
SUM(CASE WHEN [t].Monat = ' + @Periode1 + ' THEN [t].[Amount2] END) AS [Amount2Feb],
SUM(CASE WHEN [t].Monat = ' + @Periode2 + ' THEN [t].[ Amount2] END) AS [Amount2March],

FROM [dbo].[tblSales]


GROUP BY [t].[Monat],[t].[Project],[t].[Description],
[t].[Finance], --[t].[Project] AS [Entrance],

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Dynamictbl

END
GO
-- 
EXEC spMonthInfo @Periode1 = '02.2011', @Periode2 = '03.2011'
```

The Problem:   [image](http://c42i.imgup.net/img170b7.PNG)

Comment: have you check the ```cbPeriode1.SelectedValue``` value?? Are you sure it's not ```null```?

Comment: Also, have you tried running these in SQL first? How are you populating your combo boxes? Have you set a display and value member?

Comment: Ja it is not null because I have chosen / selected the values 02.2011 and 03.2011 in the comboboxes respectively before the button is clicked.
I have edited my question and added an image

Comment: Yes it working perfectly in sql as I wrote in my question:

Comment: What are the fields on datagridview1? Do they match the fields your sp is outputting. On which line of code do you get the error message? And what's bs? I don't see it declared in the code.

Comment: @Melanie. The fields should be generate automatically from the sp. bs is a `Bindingsource` which I have declared somewhere in the cocode. The error appears `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Periode1", cbPeriode1.SelectedValue.ToString());`

Comment: I don't have the column name(Periode) in the store proceduce but the the tables I union do have the columns. So how do I go about this problem?

Comment: This seems to be a poorly designed database. Why don't you keep the data in one table? I can't think of any reason to hold 24 identical tables in any database just to use a union to query them.

Comment: @Zohard. I have edited my question. Can you please take a look. I am having difficulties

Comment: From your description it seems like an application issue not a database issue (as it runs OK in the database). Why is the stored procedure using dynamic SQL? It's unnecessary. I suggest you double check what is being sent to it and also capture the SQL execution in SQL Profiler to see what really going on.